# How to use AND in Google Sheets w multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

What is the proper syntax for using `AND`, when creating a custom formula in Google Sheets? (The formula applies to a format I set in the Conditional Formatting interface.)

*H2:H2000 is greater than Today **AND** G2:G2000 is empty*

How do I properly use `AND` in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at the "Custom Formula Is" option with conditional formatting, typing in the following should work;

`=AND($H2>TODAY(),$G2="")`

This will highlight the entire row within the range.

Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking an answer for this very same question and it seems that the syntax has changed a bit and these answers no longer work. To fix them you need to replace "," with ";". So for example `=AND($H2>TODAY(),$G2="")` becomes `=AND($H2>TODAY();$G2="")` and then it should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

The following works:

```
=AND(H2:H2000 > TODAY(), ISBLANK(G2:G2000))
```

It can be applied to G2:G2000, H2:H2000, or another column; it formats the column in which it is entered.